# Unknow index of session

Tags: php

Ok guys when I try to run my simple php code I get this error: Notice: Undefined index: Status, here is my code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        --->All links
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            if($_SESSION['Status']=='1'){
        ?> 
            ...--->NAV1

        ?>  
            <?php
            }else{
        ?>
          ...NAV2--->
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
        </nav>
    </body>
```

The error is on " `if($_SESSION['Status']=='1'){`", this code will check if user is logged or not then shows a proper navbar.

Answer (score -1):

Update your line.

```
if($_SESSION['Status']=='1'){
```

to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Status']) 
&& !empty($_SESSION['Status']) 
&& $_SESSION['Status']=='1'){
```

Comment: `isset` here is redundant. It is not needed.